# Idea to send EXM message from WFFM form with custom tokens and recipient based on country

Tags: wffm, exm

Sitecore 8.2, EXM 3.4

My client would like to send an automated e-mail, triggered by submitting an WFFM form.
This is possible out of the box, however, my client would like the recipient of the triggered e-mail, to be based on a selected country from a field in the WFFM form.
Furthermore, it should be possible to add custom tokens, targeting the submitted fields from the form.

I thought this could easily be accomplished by creating a custom save action that first locates the recipient based on the country, and then triggers the automated e-mail in EXM, while setting the "To" and adds the custom tokens myself, using a Dictionary of sorts.
But it seems like the EXM API only accepts a contact Id if i am not mistaken, when trying to send an e-mail using their Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.ClientApi.SendStandardMessage() method.
How would you recommend approaching this?
We would like to take advantage of the customization/personalization/statistics of EXM.

Thanks

Comment: Long story short: upgrade to 9.0.2 or higher, use Forms, and a Custom Submit action to send sn EXM message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, be aware that WFFM is end of life and not any more part of the product. It has been replaced by Sitecore Forms module. So your custom developments will be for the dustbin when upgrading Sitecore.

To answer your question. As you can only mail to contacts, you need to create a new xdb contact or update the current contact with the email address you want to email. Then you can pass this contact through the clientapi.

Passing tokens through the client api of EXM is not possible with EXM 3.4. This feature was added in version 3.5. (https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Email%20Experience%20Manager/35/Email%20Experience%20Manager%2035%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes)